How to physically implement a CNOT gate with a photon and a cold atom?
If I have qubits in the same platform (superconducting, photon or cold atoms), the implementation of CNOT gates is relatively well-known. However, if I have a photon and a cold atom, how am I supposed to perform a CNOT gate? I assume it's through some sort of light-matter interaction, any reference for this?
